Ethers giving Error: missing revert data in call exception for some pairs
I'm trying to get quote prices for pairs. Most of them end up being successful, but some number of them raise an error in code Error: missing revert data in call exception;
What can be done about it? Why does it occur?

Sounds like those pairs don't exist, have you verified there are pairs with those token addresses and that specific fee tier as that would determine the address being checked.
